# closing windows application on windows request (like shutdown)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, shutdown, terminate

i write a windows applciation project which i perform some other action in it's form closing events, now i look for something that get called from out side, to let application close, since applciation wont close, at last in older os, it casue windows to not shutdown

here's are my form events:

in here i close my monitor over other section (i only have monitor on form load and i dont care about that part, it finish in some second)

```
private void UserInterface_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_objStop))
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_objStop);
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_objStop);
            }
        }
```

next is

```
private void UserInterface_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_flagExit)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                HideForm();
            }
        }
```

now i'm looking for the event that come form windows so i switch _flagExist to true before my application reject closing (try to hide in notification bar instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) from [`FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)

Comment: there are multi option, one is shutdown and other task manager...

what else i should choose? as windows events?

Comment: It depends on what do you exactly want :) And you should refactor your UserInterface_FormClosed - your if is useless...

Comment: i'm not sure if it do nothing, like in my service i put a lock, but the service on start, bypassed my lock :|

Comment: and i have notify icon, i want when user close form manually call hide() method, else do nothing

Comment: I meant that you can call Monitor.TryEnter without cheking its result. And then call your Monitor.Exit. As for closing there is UserClosing close reason.

Comment: if it does enter it mean i didnt enter, so i exit, and if it's dont enter it mean i already are in monitor, so i again exit

aha, got you:
you mean like this:
Monitor.TryEnter(_objStop);
Monitor.Exit(_objStop);

Comment: is it good?  
`private void UserInterface_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_flagExit && !IsWindowsCalledClosingEvent(e.CloseReason))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                HideForm();
            }
        }

        private bool IsWindowsCalledClosingEvent(CloseReason closeReason)
        {
            return closeReason==CloseReason.WindowsShutDown||closeReason==CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall||closeReason==CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing;
        }`